# Google SQL PHP No Data Showing - Connected

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to view some data via PHP. I have a SQL database with Google. I am struggling to extract the data and desperately need some help!

The PHP keeps saying there is 0 records, even though there is a number of records within the 'timing' database and 'events' table.

If anyone has any ideas why this is not working I would be very grateful!

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli('IP_ADDRESS:3306','root','PASSWORD',timing);
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully ';
$sql = "SELECT event_id FROM events";
$result = $link->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>Event ID</th><th>Event Name</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "id: " . $row["event_id"];
}
echo "</table>";
}
else {
echo "0 results";
}
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Your mixing `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` functions. Change them all to `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: I suppose `timing` on 2nd line should be in quotes - `"timing"`.

Comment: `mysql_error()` = No show error. `mysql_close($link);` = No close nothing. Going to the bar for a *rhum & coke* = Complete success (*better make that a double*). At least *those* mix well ;-)

Comment: @JayBlanchard care to join me? ^^^

Comment: Abso-freaking-lutely @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks very much, got any other ideas?

Comment: As it's been said, you need to keep all your functions as `mysqli_`, those different APIs don't mix together. Do that and try it again and see if it kicks into gear.

Comment: @Fred-ii-<?php
$link = new mysqli('IP:3306','root','PASSWORD',"timing");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully ';

$sql = "SELECT event_id FROM events";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>Event ID</th><th>Event Name</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["event_id"];
    }
 echo "</table>";
}
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>

Comment: Getting any errors from that? Plus, you should be putting that in your question and not in comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes still 0 records error!

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything else.

Comment: What Kos posted below makes sense. I was going to make a mention earlier about the word "timing" being treated as a constant. Yet, you're now using `$link = new mysqli('IP:3306','root','PASSWORD',"timing");` as you posted earlier in comments.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Will do a bit of digging, but if you have any suggestions that would be great. Got a couple of errors"Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host" "Connected successfully Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in" "Trying to get property of non-object in"

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used Google's DB API, so I won't be able to help you any further. Wish I could but am unable.

Comment: @Ryan_RCM Please update your code in the question, so we don't have to debug the same thing twice

Comment: Instead of `IP_ADDRESS:3306` try either `localhost` or `localhost:3306` or your domain name if you're registered with Google as a web host. See also https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client

Answer (score 0):

Unless `timing` is a defined constant, and it looks like that is not the case, being that a string you should wrap it in quotes or double-quotes. A non-defined constant should cast to a string in any case, but since i can't see any other error in your code that might be what is causing your issue. Try changing

```
$link = new mysqli('IP_ADDRESS:3306','root','PASSWORD',timing);
```

to

```
$link = new mysqli('IP_ADDRESS:3306', 'root', 'PASSWORD', 'timing');
```

Comment: It makes sense, however OP posted in comments that is now using `$link = new mysqli('IP:3306','root','PASSWORD',"timing");`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i think i got it. From PHP.net:

> OO syntax only: If a connection fails an object is still returned. To check if the connection failed then use either the mysqli_connect_error() function or the mysqli->connect_error property as in the preceding examples.

This means `$link` in your code will always be a MySQLi resource, and that it will always cast to `true`. What you need to do is to check your resource object for errors properly, like this:

```
if ($link->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error: ' . $link->connect_error);
```